# Carousel Slider for Custom Theme in Shopify

Tags: jquery, css, shopify

I am currently creating a custom theme in Shopify using the Timber Framework and one of the requirements is to add a carousel slider that will show 3 boxed images that will slide automatically, as well as having the left/right buttons to allow the user to manually change the slider.

I am not sure if I will need to create something from scratch so was looking for some advice on how I should tackle this.

Comment: may be you can use twiiter bootstrap carousel slider it fullfills all your conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would typically use http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/ on a Shopify theme. To get you started, something like the following should get you up and running:

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  'items': 1,
  'navigation': true,
  'navigationText': ['<','>'],
  'pagination': false
});
```

Then just read the docs for creating the elements needed. This particular slider has swipe enabled which is handy for mobile users too.

Comment: Thank you Alex, i will give that a go. Just to clarify, would i be able to use this multiple times on different pages?

Comment: That's correct, if each carousel has different settings then just repeat the above init function for each individual carousel and call it on an id selector e.g. #mobile-carousel /  #desktop-carousel

Comment: Thank you Alex : )

Comment: Alex you are a star, i have managed to add the carousel onto my site and its all working!

Comment: Btw, is there any way i can move the buttons to each side?